# Image Click php open another php Site and send Image href to second php

Tags: php

I have the following code from mysql.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movies")) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<span class="image">';
        echo'<img id="'. $row["movie_ID"] .'" src=" ' .$row["bild"]. ' "/>';
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<a href=" ' . $row["link"] . ' ">';
        echo '<h2>' . $row["name"] . '</h2>';
        echo '<div class="content">';
        echo '<p>' . $row["short"] . '</p>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0!";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

My code works, but now I want to change it so that when I click on it, it opens my defined php site and my image href is input there.

Comment: When you click on what?

Comment: Maybe pass your image and link at GET or POST parameters?

Comment: these are videos and pictures from mysql. i have player.php, when i click on picture i want to send parameter to player.php

Comment: Is there any reason why you couldn't just pass them as GET or POST?

Comment: I'm not such a professional, I'm just learning, and I'm making home video library.

can you please show me somehow how I could do it?

Comment: Read this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Comment: I've read a lot, but problem with me is the automatically produced images with link. I have no input form, so I did not know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Russ J,i read more, what you told me, then I changed code.

```
$video = $row["link"];
echo '<a href="/videoteka.ado/player.php?video= ' . $video. ' ">';
```

player.php

```
<? Php
 $ movie_link = $ _GET ["video"];
?>
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your task correctly, then you need something like that:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM movies")) {

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo '<a href=" ' . $row["link"] . ' ">';
            echo '<span class="image">';
            echo '<img id="' . $row["movie_ID"] . '" src=" ' . $row["bild"] . ' "/>';
            echo '</span>';
            echo '<h2>' . $row["name"] . '</h2>';
            echo '<div class="content">';
            echo '<p>' . $row["short"] . '</p>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</a>';

        }
    } else {
        echo "0!";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

Comment: these are automatically generated images from db, images have href link of movies, I've made a another php site, player.php. I want if I click on the picture the href from picture in player.php page transfer. Do you understand now?

Comment: No. I wrap image into link. You did not specify in the question about the player.php and I suggested that this link in $row["link"]. Learn to ask questions before putting a minus.

Comment: I did not give you a minus, I do not know who that was, I just wrote komentar